# Oracle Apex, Trying to pick value in Checkbox based on time

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I've setup a dynamic action to run javascript code to pick either "A" or "B" based on what time it is. If the time is between 07:00 (h24:mm) and 17:50 (h24:mm) it should set the value to "A", else "B".

I've got a field (P4_TIME_RECORDED) on the form that pulls the current time using this code

```
select to_char(systimestamp,'hh24:mm') as timestamp from dual
```

and a field (P4_SHIFT) that is a checkbox between A and B. [checkbox example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY562.png)

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the explanation in your question I'd go for a slightly different approach.

- The value needs to be Shift A *or* Shift B. A radio group seems to be most appropriate there, since only one value can be selected at any time.
- The value is based on sysdate, not on something that is changed *after* the page is rendered, so a dynamic action is overkill. Instead you can use a computation to get the value at page rendering time.

So this is what I'd do

- Create a page item P4_SHIFT of type **radio group** (Static values, values A and B)
- Add a **computation** on P4_SHIFT with processing point *before regions* of type *Expression* with source

```
  CASE 
    WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24MI') BETWEEN '0700' AND '1750' 
    THEN 'A'
    ELSE 'B'
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a DA and set it to be fired on page load.

- set value -> from SQL Query

my query would be something like

```
select 
    case 
        when sysdate between time_1 and time_2 
        then 'A'
        else 'B'
    end as res
from(
    select
        trunc(sysdate) + interval '7' hour as time_1,
        trunc(sysdate) + interval '17' hour + interval'50' minute as time_2 
    from dual)
```

and ofcourse, affected element has to be set as your cbx item.